SharePoint SE Aggregated Newsfeed does not work after updates
After applying march 2024 patches on a SharePoint Subscription farm the aggregated newsfeed is stuck on:

We're still collecting the latest news. You may see more if you try again a little later

ULS logs show unexpected errors regarding Distributed Cache

Unexpected error occurred in method 'BulkGet' , usage 'FeedCache' - Exception 'System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[System.String,System.Object]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[System.String,System.Byte[]]]'.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCache.BulkGet[T](IEnumerable`1 keys, String regionName)'.

and..

Unexpected exception in FeedCacheService.GetConsolidatedFeed: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[System.String,System.Object]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[System.String,System.Byte[]]]'..:
at Microsoft.Office.Server.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCache.BulkGet[T](IEnumerable1 keys, String regionName)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.FeedCache.FeedCacheDataCacheWrapper.BulkGetCachedObjects[T](IEnumerable1 keys, String regionName)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.FeedCache.FeedCacheImplementation.GetLastModifiedTimes(List1 entities, Boolean& resultsIncomplete, FeedCacheEntity requestingEntity)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.FeedCache.FeedCacheImplementation.GetConsolidatedFeed(FeedCacheEntity entity, List1 followedEntities, Int32 maxItemsPerEntity, Int32 maxNumberEntities, Int32 maxTotalItems, TimeSpan timeout, Nullable1 newerThan, Nullable1 olderThan)
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.SPMicrofeedFeedCacheService.GetConsolidatedFeed(FeedCacheRetrievalEntity fcRetEntity, List1 followedEntities, FeedCacheRetrievalOptions fcRetOptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FeedCacheService.Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IFeedCacheService.GetConsolidatedFeed(FeedCacheRetrievalEntity fcRetEntity, List1 followedEntities, FeedCacheRetrievalOptions fcRetOptions)

I've tried to remove and add the servers to the cache cluster. Delete and create a new User Profile Application. Does anyone have any ideas or solutions?

Seem's to be the same error that was introduced to 2016 environments with the 2023 november CU - but was fixed in the march 2024 CU. You might have to open a ticket with Microsoft. https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2024/02/09/trending-issue-sp2016-aggregated-newsfeeds-are-failing-to-load-after-installation-of-the-november-2023-cu-or-newer/

there's a new patch: https://support.microsoft.com/en-US/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-subscription-edition-april-9-2024-kb5002581-fdd49ab7-b4be-46d2-aca4-0ac3268e0803
seems to fix it perhaps, will try and report back

Yeah, that should fix it (with some other annoying bug's that been introduced lately).

FYI the patch works and solves my issue https://support.microsoft.com/en-US/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-subscription-edition-april-9-2024-kb5002581-fdd49ab7-b4be-46d2-aca4-0ac3268e0803

Latest april 2024 patch solves this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-US/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-subscription-edition-april-9-2024-kb5002581-fdd49ab7-b4be-46d2-aca4-0ac3268e0803
